# Set basic auth on homepage only nginx

Tags: nginx

I have below configuration. I only want to authorize `/` because the only one that has a UI. Other URLs are already apis like `/report/`, `/group/`, `/delete/` and so on.

```
upstream gofastdfs{
    server localhost:8081;
    keepalive 32;
}


server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name         localhost;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types '*';

    location / {
        auth_basic           "Caution";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
        keepalive_timeout 620;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass      http://gofastdfs;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

But my configuration authorizes every URL, I only want to limit to `/`

Comment: why not make it `location  /index.html`? https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: I do not have `index.html` to begin with

Comment: Add a `location = /` which will handle only `/` and that leaves `location /` to handle every other URI.

Comment: Wow you are correct

Answer (score 0):

`location /` matches any URI that is not handled by some other `location` block - i.e. it is the default `location`.

`location = /` only matches the single URI `/`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You can split your configuration into two `location` blocks using one with authentication and the other without. Some statements will need to be duplicated between both `location` blocks, but most can be moved into the outer context.

For example:

```
keepalive_timeout 620;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

location = / {
    auth_basic           "Caution";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
    proxy_pass      http://gofastdfs;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://gofastdfs;
}
```